# Single mouse clicks behaving as double clicks?

Tags: 10.04, mouse

Some time ago I started experiencing strange issue when single clicks would intermittently act as double clicks. 
Replacing the mouse doesn't help. 
Ubuntu forum seems to have few threads related to this( [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371815), and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444878) and few more) with no definitive solution.

Hence my question - maybe someone here will be able to help me solve this mystery?

Comment: I have a uf-thread and a bug on this too. My "solution" basically involved a new motherboard, a new mouse, a SSD and a reinstall. I didn't upgrade all of these because of the problem but upgrading them did fix the issue.

Comment: wow, seems a bit expensive :) but the thing is, before the latest 10.04 install this was working fine on the same hardware on the same OS(10.04)

Comment: It seems to happen when I use resource intensive programs. I usually have to perform a reboot and it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found [the bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-180/+bug/410805). Bryce seems to suggest that it might be a Nvidia issue (that's how it has been filed since).

But yes, try another mouse. Try a different version of the nvidia driver (you can update to the x-swat PPA for the latest versions -- or install it manually) and if you're at your wits' end, splash out a monkey load of money on a £300 motherboard, £100 mouse and £150 SSD. If nothing else, it'll give you some retail therapy.

This effected me in 9.10 and I did my upgrade some time before moving to 10.04 so this could easily be completely unrelated.

Comment: New drivers for Nvidia worked... I can't make a connection between video card driver and mouse in my brain, but whatever... thanks for the advice :)